# Como executar uma função PHP várias vezes?

Tags: php

Tenho essa função em PHP, ela executa um código em Python que retorna a temperatura vinda do Arduino.

Eu preciso que ela seja executada a cada 2 segundos para que eu possa exibir na tela do navegador a informação atualizada.

Qual seria a melhor maneira para fazer isso?

```
function retornaTemperatura()
{
    $comando = escapeshellcmd('temperatura.py');// Local do arquivo python
    return shell_exec($comando);// retorna o valor do py para exibir ou mandar para  um banco de dados
}
```

Comment: "Exibir **na tela** as informações atualizadas". Vai fazer isso via linha de comando ou via browser? Você não detalhou isso na pergunta. São dois caminhos diferentes.

Comment: Quero exibir no browser

Comment: Cria uma tarefa cron de 2 em 2 segundos no servidor para executar seu script.

Comment: Poderia fazer o contrário onde o próprio arduino envia a informação ao invés de estar sempre a consultar o dispositivo a cada segundo. O "desgaste" é menor. Mas como não foi o isso que perguntou, evitarei responder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Web é algo que sempre vai ter a resposta completa, se usar um `sleep` você terá problemas, dores de cabeça, principalmente se tiver `session_start`, entenda que não estou dizendo que o sleep é ruim, só estou dizendo que o uso da maneira proposta nas demais respostas não é o ideal.

Acredito que o melhor seja usar Ajax e popular um DIV, por exemplo:

**foo/temperatura.php**

```
<?php
function retornaTemperatura()
{
    // Local do arquivo python
    $comando = escapeshellcmd('temperatura.py');

    // retorna o valor do py para exibir ou mandar para  um banco de dados
    return shell_exec($comando);
}

echo retornaTemperatura();
```

E na sua página chame algo assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="temperatura"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function temperatura()
{
    var el = document.getElementById("temperatura");
    var segundos = 2; //2 segundos de espera
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Defina como true
    oReq.open("GET", "/foo/temperatura.php", true);

    //Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (oReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (oReq.status == 200) {
                el.innerHTML = oReq.responseText;
            }

            setTimeout(temperatura, segundos * 1000);
        }
    };

    //Envia a requisição, mas a resposta fica sendo aguardada em Background
    oReq.send(null);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim:

```
while(true) {
    retornaTemperatura();
    sleep(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Obs.:** Como não foi dado maiores detalhes sobre a execução da função, me contive em mostrar um exemplo de como repetir a execução em PHP apenas, como se fosse uma linguagem de script para ser executada diretamente no sistema operacional (e não pela web). Eu não vou formular uma resposta para o segundo caso, pois a do [@GuilhermeNascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/162653/18246) está completa e vai te atender.

---

Você vai ter que chamar a função várias vezes, esperando um certo intervalo de tempo a cada chamada.

Para isso, é possível usar a função [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep), ela recebe como parâmetro a quantidade de segundos que o script vai esperar até continuar a execução.

```
while(true){
    $valor = retornaTemperatura();
    sleep(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso, é criando um agendador de tarefas para executar seu script a cada 2 segundos. Para fazer isso, vai depender de qual é o servidor windows ou linux, e de uma certa configuração no apache.

Para servidor Linux:

```
crontab -e
2/* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /usr/var/www/seu_script.php
```

Para windows pode seguir [**este exemplo**](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-with-windows).

Porém, se esse script vai ficar rodando apenas quando executado (uma única vez), pode fazer algo assim:

```
function retornaTemperatura()
{
   $comando = escapeshellcmd('temperatura.py');// Local do arquivo python
   echo shell_exec($comando);
}
while (true) {
    try {
        retornaTemperatura();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh'" .
           "content='2;url=" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "'>";
    }
    sleep(2); // aguarda 2 segundos
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, os exemplos estão bons, mas CRONTAB é algo que não tem haver com página de web, ele executa como CLI, nunca chegará o tal resultado para o usuário, e o segundo exemplo não tem necessidade do sleep quando ocorre o excetpion, já que o meta tem 2s, seria melhor move-lo para dentro do `try`, são dicas apenas. Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Answer (score -1):

ou caso vc queira limitar o número de execuções vc pode fazer assim

```
$num_max=10;
$delay=1; // 1 segundo de pausa entre cada execução
for($i=1;$i<=$num_max;$i++){
    retornaTemperatura();
    sleep($delay);
}
```

assim vc controla quantas vezes vai executar e qual o tempo de espera vc tem.